# why my "gets" function can't really get a string?

Tags: c, string, gets

My problem looks very simple and im so sorry for asking but what its wrong with this code?! why is just skipping the name part?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define nl printf("\n")

struct date{int day,month,year;};
struct student{long int id;char name[30];struct date birthday;};

int main()
{
    struct student temp;
    nl;nl;printf("ID no:");scanf("%ld",&temp.id);nl;
    printf("Student name:");
    gets(temp.name);
    nl;nl;
    printf("Student birthday year:19");scanf("%d",&temp.birthday.year);nl;
    printf("Student birthday month");scanf("%d",&temp.birthday.month);nl;
    printf("Student birthday day");scanf("%d",&temp.birthday.day);nl;
    getch();        //for pause
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything wrong about gets function?! cause i don't want to use `scanf("%s",)` because of space thing...

Comment: Regarding _"Student birthday year:19"_, are you writing this for this century?

Comment: i'm a new programmer sorry for not having the knowledge ...

Comment: `#define nl printf("\n")` is horrible C, and should never be in a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it reads the `\n` character left behind by `scanf`. Use

```
int ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

to consume `\n`.

And better not to use `gets` as it fails in array bound check. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: *Do not* use `gets`, as was explained. Use `fgets` and read from `stdin`. `gets` is very unsafe as there are many issues with it: see [here for a basic explanation](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html).

Answer (score 0):

As said by haccks, you should not use gets(), but if you really want to use it in your code use `gets()` before the id no. ie after the `struct student temp;` line,  and if you want to print it then simply `puts(temp.name)` .